# Add "reviewedby" in Wordpress posts

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields, review

​Hello,

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to add "reviewedby" + name (potentially with a blue checkmark) under the author as displayed in the attached example.

​Also, I would like users to be able to click on the reviewed name and access an archive page (as it happens for the author) in which it's shown his/her photo, name and description with all the article he/her has reviewed.
At the end of each article, however, I'd like to keep the author box only, without another one for the reviewer.

I already created the custom fields with ACF WP plugin, but then I don't know how to show them on the front-end, or in which part of the php code to add it.

Thank you very much

Comment: What theme are you using? Does it use a page builder? You want to find the code that currently writes the by-line, which is possibly in single.php in your theme folder, or a file that that includes, or a block that it includes, etc.

Comment: I am using Soledad theme https://themeforest.net/item/soledad-multiconcept-blogmagazine-wp-theme/12945398#item-description__update-changelog

I don't know where to get the code related to the reviewedby custom field and where to place it in the single.php

Comment: You could try asking the authors for help if you're a paying customer? Look for "the_author" in the templates: it might be get_the_author() or the_author_something(), but that should find you the by-line. You can take some inspiration for the link code from those functions in wp-includes/author-template.php, but you'd probably have to build your own reviewed-by archive page though.

Comment: where you'd place the code is going to be theme specific, and you might need to make CSS changes to get it to look how you want, it's not something people online can help you with unless they also had a copy of the theme. The part we could help you with is sadly the bit you've already figured out. For how to display an ACF field you should look at the ACF docs ( probably `the_field` but 3rd party plugins/themes like ACF are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope )